# Get other player's id in a 1vs1 turn based game

Tags: android, google-play-services

What is the simplest way to get both players' ids to use in the `takeTurn` method in a 1vs1 game.

I know I can get the first one by simply calling `TurnBasedMatch.getCreatorId()` but how can I get the other one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Participant Id that you want for `takeTurn`. You get these using `TurnBasedMatch.getParticipantIds()`.

You can then work out which is which by getting the player's Particpant Id using `TurnBasedMatch.getParticipantId(String)` - passing in the players Id.